# Move Ball With Same Velocity on Slope - Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move ball with on incoming slopes as like it was moving in plain ground. At present when slope started ball velocity get reduced so overall ball movement get reduced as per game player experience.

I want to keep same velocity when its moving on ground or sloppy areas.

Though following image I tried to explain my problem:
[image]

Here is the code snippet that I was using:

```
void FixedUpdate ()
{

    if (!GameManager.Instance.IsGameRunninng) {
        myRigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        return;
    }

    if (isJumper) {
        isJumper = false;
        myRigidBody.AddForce (Vector3.up * 35f, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    isGrounded = Physics.Raycast (rayTransform.position, Vector3.down, 0.5f, groundMask);

    Vector3 nextVelocity = myRigidBody.velocity;
    nextVelocity.x = ballInputHandler.horizontalInput * smoothnessX;

    if (!isGrounded) {
        nextVelocity.y -= speed * 0.3f;
    } else {
        nextVelocity.y = 0;
        nextVelocity.z = speed;
    }

    myRigidBody.velocity = Vector3.Lerp (myRigidBody.velocity, nextVelocity, smoothnessValue * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

    ClampingBallMovement ();

}
```

I hope you got my problem correctly, give me some suggestion so I can come over from this problem.

Comment: your problem is `nextVelocity.y = 0;` here you destroy a part of your velocity vector. if you want to keep the horizontal velocity when you start moving on a slope, you have to rotate the velocity vector. horizontal velocity (5,0) can become (4,3) on a slope - see http://www.azionetradizionale.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/teorema-di-Pitagora-634x506.jpg

Comment: if you know the angle of the slope, you can use https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/images/sin-cos-tan.svg to get `new.x = old.x * cos(angle)` and `new.y = old.y * sin(angle)`

Comment: where is image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you've adjusted the `nextVelocity.y` component:

```
    myRigidBody.velocity = nextVelocity.normalized * desiredSpeed;
```

Comment: so my overall code what will become ? I want to use Lerping as well

Comment: Why do you need the Lerp?